# Mule Management Console and previously deployed applicaticons

Tags: mule

I have certain applications deployed on mule Enterprise server,  the deployable archive was placed in the apps directory and deployed, the deployment was not done via the management console.

I would like to know if it is possible to bring these previously deployed applications under the deployments tab of management console without redeploying the application.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MMC **only** tracks application deployed through it. There is no mechanism implemented OOTB either on MMC or on the Runtime to discover what is already deployed on the runtime(s) connected to it. The same applies to MMC replacement, Anypoint Runtime Manager.